# Excel Sheet Upload to Sql Server Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am working in asp.net project and task is to upload excel file and on upload button click, entries must be store to Ms. Sql Server 2008 DB Table.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an SQL stored procedure that reads the Excel file an inserts the rows into a SQL table. Example below:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableName (Column1, Column2)
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Import\MySpreadsheet.xls;IMEX=1', [Sheet1$])
```

See [MSDN OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) for further info.

Comment: I have to save the file-contents into database table. Please tell me the query that i can use on button click event ..

Comment: Do you use SQL Server Management Studio?